# Stone Game (leetcode 877) - how is the sum getting calculated

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, dynamic-programming

Summary of Game Game - There are even number of piles of stones, and each of the 2 players picks up a pile alternately. Sum of the stones is always odd, hence there cannot be a tie.  We need to check if the player who starts first wins the game.

I've a question about the following code, which is working fine
This code checks whether Play A (who goes first) wins a game 
Code below calculates the (sum of stones picked up by A - sum of stones picked up by B)

Question is - how is the code **(under code if(parity == 0))** calculating the sum.
I understand **dynamic programming/recursion** is involved, however **since the sum is not being passed in the recursive call - how is the sum calculated** ?

```
def stoneGame(self, piles:List[int]) -> bool :
        N = len(piles)

        @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
        def dp(i, j):

            if(i > j):
                return 0

            parity = (j - i +1) %2
            if(parity == 0):
                return max(piles[i] + dp(i+1, j), piles[j] + dp(i, j-1))
            else:
                return min(-piles[i] + dp(i+1, j), -piles[j] + dp(i, j-1))


        return dp(0, N-1) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

lets look at the term **piles[i] + dp(i+1, j)** and parity 0.

next calculation will be **piles[i] - Piles[i+1] + dp(i+2,j)** or **piles[i] - Piles[j] + dp(i+1,j -1)**

So you can observe how the piles array is either getting added or subtracted depending on the conditions.

At the base case **( i > j)** the calculation will be the following:

**piles[x1] - piles[x2] + piles[x3] - piles[x4] + ......**

where the x1,x2,x3,x4 are different indexes of the array.